# how to pass HashSet object from from one Fragment to another Fragment in android

Tags: android

i want to Pass Hash_set object when click on button,object pass from one fragment to another fragment. in Hash_set object I Put multiple Parse Object in Hash_set object .How to do it ? i tried with Intent and Bundle but not get successful to pass object.
please provide me any best idea. thanks `

Comment: Add a "getter" and use it in the other activity.

Comment: Send it using intent, bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Also use Application.

step1:Use this class

```
public class JsonApplication extends Application {

public JSONObject jsonObject;

public JSONObject getJsonObject() {
    return jsonObject;
}

public void setJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
}}
```

step2: set data and get data as your desire

Answer (score 1):

Simply, create an static object of your hashset in the activity like this,

```
public static Set<YourObject> mObject = new HashSet<YourObject>();
```

and from your BaseAdapter-button-onClick call it in this way,

```
ActivityName.mObject = mYourHashSet;
```

> A public static field/method
>
> An alternate way to make data accessible across Activities/Services is
>   to use public static fields and/or methods. You can access these
>   static fields from any other class in your application. To share an
>   object, the activity which creates your object sets a static field to
>   point to this object and any other activity that wants to use this
>   object just accesses this static field.

#### Other way todo this,

In you baseAdapter-onClick, convert it to JSONObject like that,

```
JSONObject multiple = new JSONObject();
multiple.put("hash_set_object", mHashSetObject);
Intent ii = new Intent(mActivity, ActivityName.class);
ii.putExtra("hash_set_json", multiple.toString());
startActivity(ii);
```

In Activity's onCreate call it in this way,

```
String HashString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hash_set_json");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(new JsonObject(HashString).getString("hash_set_object"));
//Now make for-loop to re-populate hashSet from JSONArray
```

Comment: thanks for your your answer. please say any other way to do it . I do not want to create a static object because object size is large. please say any other option.

Comment: thanks brother . i get my answer. please like my question also. because i can not able to like your answer.